# How to make this `echo | bc` output be on the same line as the echo output after?

Tags: shell-script

I'm making a program for generating random numbers, and before it generates, I want to show how many combinations there are. When I do it, I get this:

```
64k@conroe$ bash random A-Za-z0-9 3
238328
possible combinations
CG1
```

I want 'possible combinations' to be on the same line as '238328', so I get

```
238328 possible combinations
```

Here's the code for said section:

```
if [ $1 == 'A-Z' ] || [ $1 ==  'a-z' ]
then
    echo "26^$2" | bc 
elif [ $1 == 'A-Za-z' ] || [ $1 ==  'a-zA-Z' ]
then
    echo "52^$2" | bc
elif [ $1 == 'A-Z0-9' ] || [ $1 ==  'a-z0-9' ]
then
    echo "36^$2" | bc
elif [ $1 == 'A-Za-z0-9' ] ||[ $1 == 'a-zA-Z0-9' ]
then
    echo "62^$2" | bc
else
    echo "${#$1}^$2" | bc 

fi
echo "possible combinations"
```

If there's any way to make this shorter as well, I would love to get suggestions. I'm still relatively new to bash scripting.

Also, is there any possible way to get the `echo | bc` to output a number separated by commas? Some of the numbers can get really large, i.e for `random A-Za-z0-9 10` the number of possible combinations is `839299365868340224`. I want that to be comma separated so it shows `839,299,365,868,340,224`.
Full code:

```
if [ $1 == 'A-Z' ] || [ $1 ==  'a-z' ]
then
    echo "26^$2" | bc 
elif [ $1 == 'A-Za-z' ] || [ $1 ==  'a-zA-Z' ]
then
    echo "52^$2" | bc
elif [ $1 == 'A-Z0-9' ] || [ $1 ==  'a-z0-9' ]
then
    echo "36^$2" | bc
elif [ $1 == 'A-Za-z0-9' ] ||[ $1 == 'a-zA-Z0-9' ]
then
    echo "62^$2" | bc
else
    echo "${#$1}^$2" | bc 

fi
echo "possible combinations"
if [ $# == 2 ]
then
    < /dev/urandom env LC_CTYPE=C tr -dc $1 | head -c $2 | while read -n 1 x 
    do
    printf "\e[1;36m$x"
    sleep 0.03
    done
    echo -e '\033[0m'
    exit 0
exit 1
elif [ $# == 3 ]
then

for (( c=1; c<=$3; c++ ))
 do {
        < /dev/urandom env LC_CTYPE=C tr -dc $1 | head -c $2 | while read -n 1 x 
    do
    printf "\e[0;33m$x"
    sleep 0.03
    done
    echo -e '\033[0m'
}
done


exit 1
fi
```

Comment: can you post your entire script to review it?

Comment: @saulortega I'm away right now, I'll post the full script when I get home.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If nothing else, you need a `case` statement.

```sh
random(){
        printf "%d^${2##*[!0-9]*}\n"  "$(($(
                export  LC_ALL=C; a=$1
                while   x=${a%"${a#?}"} s=
                        case  $a     in
                        ([a-z]-["$x"-z]*|[A-Z]-["$x"-Z]*)
                                a=${a#??} s=?
                                printf  '(%d-%d+1)+' "'$a" "'$x";;
                        ([0-9]-["$x"-9]*)
                                x=${a%"${a#???}"} a=${a#"$x"}
                                printf  "$((-($x)+1))+";;
                        (?-*)   a=${a#??}
                                echo 2+;;
                        (?*)    x=${a%%[A-Za-z0-9]-*}
                                a=${a#"$x"}
                                echo "${#x}+";;
                        (*) !   echo 0          ;;esac
                do              a=${a#$s}       ; done
        )))"    |       bc|     sed 's/$/ possibilities./
                                      /^1 /s/....$/y./'
}
```

Ok, I have to apologize - I only now realized that what I thought were char classes were literal arg strings - and that you were parsing them. Now I understand what you're about. I made it work just now - it will actually *do* the ranges, and you can handle any kind of character - because it counts the difference.

```
{   random A 1       #1  char        and 1
    random AB 1      #2  chars       and 1
    random a-Z 1     #3  chars because the range is invalid and 1
    random aa-c 1    #4  chars: aabc and 1
    random a-c 2     #3  chars: abc  and 2
    random aa-z 3)   #27 chars:aa-z  and 3
}
```

#### OUTPUT

```
1 possibility.
2 possibilities.
3 possibilities.
4 possibilities.
9 possibilities.
19683 possibilities.
```

The first thing that is done is we try to `printf` our second argument - which undergoes `${2##*[!0-9]*}` parameter expansion to render it null if it contains any non-numeric character - preceded by the `%d`igit value of an arithmetic expansion in which our entire run loop occurs. In fact, the entire function is one `printf` statement from the perspective of the current shell.

But within the `$((`math expansion`))` is a `$(`command substitution`)` - and that is all. We provide it with no numbers - it is just `$(($()))`.

Except that the subshell within the command substitution runs our loop and collects our output. Our output eventually adds up to a viable arithmetic expression.

Within the loop we always put `$a`'s first char in `$x` at the top of each. Next we check the head of our current value for `$a` against some `case` patterns. The first of these looks like this:

```
([a-z]-["$x"-z]*|[A-Z]-["$x"-Z]*)
```

Here we're using `$a`'s first character - which we saved in `$x` - twice. In the first place it is the argument against which we compare our pattern. But in the second place it is a limiter for our `$a`'s third character - it ensures that not only does the third character fit within an alphabetics range, but also that it is greater than or equal to `$a`'s first character. Because `z-a` is an invalid range and doesn't match when we use `$x` to test.

If we match this pattern we printf the ascii digit value of each of `$x` and `$a` after we strip from the head `$a` two characters.

Like this:

```
printf '(%d-%d+1)+' "'$x" "'$a"
```

...which becomes a paranthetical subexpression in our end arithmetic, and evaluates to the distance between our range.

We do the same thing for the digits:

```
 ([0-9]-["$x"-9]*)
```

And we strip the head off `$a` in that case as well. The math for the digits is a little different - we get the negative. `$a`'s first three chars are saved in `$x`, like `x=4-9`.

And so we print:

```
printf "$((-($x)+1))+"
```

In the event that the head of `$a` *looks* like a range but still managed to fail the previous two tests, and so matches our `(?-*)` pattern, then we'll strip the top two characters, `echo 2+`, and cycle again.

If we make it as far down as the pattern `(?*)` then we will strip from the head of `$a` everything up to the first occurring possible range match in `$a`. If we're successful we'll continue to loop and just split the difference, but if there is no possible range match in the remainder of `$a`, we'll quit the loop because we'll consume all of `$a` right here and echo `${#a}+`, basically.

Well, we won't quit it *yet* - the loop doesn't ever quit until `$a` is sent back to the top of the loop empty. When that happens we do `! echo 0` which is the last string we write to output.

And so come back to the current shell and evaluate everything in the math expansion to print `"$((subshell_math))^$2"` at `bc` whose output is piped to `sed` which appends the string `possibles.` to its output.

And that's how it works.

Comment: Heh, nice edit. I was just about to say that it didn't work with the `0-9` argument. Would you mind explaining the code so I'm able to understand how it actually works?

Comment: @ViktorAhlström - I just fixed it *again* - it was one too few.

Comment: @ViktorAhlström - done now.

Comment: Thanks! I'm still relatively new to shell scripts and that was a really nice clear-cut explanation for me.

Comment: @ViktorAhlström - there are no `bash`isms in this. It will run as well - probably better - in `dash`. It's all standard, POSIX shell-script.

Comment: I have to run it as `bash` because the section that prints out the generated string is written in `bash`. I used your section as a function that is run at the start. I named it `combo()` and it is run as `combo $1 $2`

Comment: @ViktorAhlström - of course - you can run it however you want, It should work in any shell, really.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24939/discussion-between-viktor-ahlstrom-and-mikeserv).

Answer (score 0):

I would save the output using backticks, then you can format it with printf:

```
if [ $1 == 'A-Z' ] || [ $1 ==  'a-z' ]
then
    combinations=`echo "26^$2" | bc`
elif [ $1 == 'A-Za-z' ] || [ $1 ==  'a-zA-Z' ]
    combinations=`echo "52^$2" | bc`
# ... and so on ...
fi

printf "%'.0f possible combinations\n" $combinations
```

As far as cleaning up your code, it's a little harder without knowing how you are using the parameters later, but one thing I would change is checking the pieces you are expecting one at a time instead of looking for all possible permutations.

```
#!/bin/bash

chars='0'
if  [[ $1 == *"0-9"* ]]; then
    chars="$chars+10"
fi
if  [[ $1 == *"a-z"* ]]; then
    chars="$chars+26"
fi
if  [[ $1 == *"A-Z"* ]]; then
    chars="$chars+26"
fi

combinations=`echo "($chars)^$2" | bc`
printf "%'.0f possible combinations\n" $combinations
```